# Fastest way to convert huge dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {A: {A: 0,
  B: 1,
  C: 1,
  D: 2,
  E: 2,
  F: 2,
  G: 2,
  H: 2,
  I: 3},
 B: {B: 0,
  A: 1,
  K: 1,
  O: 1,
  M: 1,
  Q: 1,
  L: 1,
  Z: 2,
  T: 2},
 C: {C: 0,
  R: 1,
  A: 1,
  D: 2,
  F: 2,
  J: 2,
  E: 2,
  Y: 2,
  B: 2},
 D: {D: 0,
  F: 1,
  H: 1,
  I: 1,
  E: 1,
  A: 2,
  C: 2,
  S: 2,
  U: 3}
```

But in fact it is way bigger (up to 60K keys) and I need a very fast and efficient way to turn this dictionary into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
person_1     person_2    degree
   A            A          0
   A            B          1 
   A            C          1
   A            D          2
   A            E          2 
   A            F          2
   A            G          2
   A            H          2 
   A            I          3
   B            B          0
   B            A          1 
   B            K          1 
   B            O          1
   B            M          1 
   B            Q          1 
   B            L          1
   B            Z          2 
   B            T          2 
   C            C          0
   C            R          1 
   C            A          1 
   C            D          2
   C            F          2 
   C            J          2 
   C            E          2
   C            Y          2 
   C            B          2
   D            D          0
   D            F          1 
   D            H          1 
   D            I          1
   D            E          1 
   D            A          2 
   D            C          2
   D            S          2 
   D            U          3
```

So basically I need a dataframe where each comes from the dictionary keys and their values, and the third column is the number inside that key. What I'm doing right now is to convert the dictionary to df using `df = pd.DataFrame(dict)` and then

```
df = pd.melt(df, 'index').rename(columns = {'index': 'hcp_npi', 
                                            'variable':'connected_hcp_npi', 
                                            'value': 'degree_of_separation'}).dropna()
```

And I get the result I need. But the problem with this approach is that when the dictionary exceeds 20K keys, the melt function just takes forever to run. So I'm looking a faster or more efficient way to go from the initial dictionary to the last dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "20K keys", do you mean top-level or combined between the top and second levels?

Comment: I mean top level keys @Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's faster to pre-process the dictionary into the column values:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    d2['person_1'] += [k] * len(v)
    d2['person_2'] += list(v.keys())
    d2['degree'] += list(v.values())

df = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I tested your method, @jezrael, @BENYs (now deleted) and mine using `timeit` and code like this (replacing the `stmt` as appropriate):

```py
timeit.timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'E': 2, 'F': 2, 'G': 2, 'H': 2, 'I': 3},
 'B': {'B': 0, 'A': 1, 'K': 1, 'O': 1, 'M': 1, 'Q': 1, 'L': 1, 'Z': 2, 'T': 2},
 'C': {'C': 0, 'R': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 2, 'F': 2, 'J': 2, 'E': 2, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2},
 'D': {'D': 0, 'F': 1, 'H': 1, 'I': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'S': 2, 'U': 3}
 }
''',
stmt='''
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.melt(df).rename(columns = {'index': 'hcp_npi', 
                                            'variable':'connected_hcp_npi', 
                                            'value': 'degree_of_separation'}).dropna()
''',
number=1000)
```

For 1000 iterations, the results were:

```
Nick      0.2878
jezrael   0.3178
BENY      2.2822
TomasCB   2.2774
```

For reference, I include @BENY answer here:

```py
pd.concat({x : pd.Series(y) for x , y in d.items()}).reset_index()
```

Comment: If possible, can you test my answer for performance?

Comment: @jezrael done. It's slightly (about 7%) slower than mine.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you. But maybe for 60k keys ouput should be different, maybe some pandas solution should be faster (I guess)

Comment: @jezrael yeah, it could be. I don't really have the time to set up such a large example to test it...

Comment: Sure, maybe I try it.

Comment: This worked really good @Nick

Comment: Hi @Nick, could you please explain me briefly how does that for loop works ? Thanks!

Comment: @TomasC8 it's creating a dict-of-lists structure that maps to your desired output in the question. It iterates over your dictionary, which has keys (`k`) whose values are nested dictionaries (`v`). In each iteration the `person_1` list gets `len(v)` copies of `k` added to it, the `person_2` list gets the keys of `v` added to it and the `degree` list gets the values of `v` added to it. If you copy my sample code from the answer and add a `print(d2)` to the end of the loop that might also help explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with flatten values for list of tuples nd then pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, k1, v1) for k, v in d.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()], 
                  columns=['person_1','person_2','degree'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   person_1 person_2  degree
0         A        A       0
1         A        B       1
2         A        C       1
3         A        D       2
4         A        E       2
5         A        F       2
6         A        G       2
7         A        H       2
8         A        I       3
9         B        B       0
10        B        A       1
11        B        K       1
12        B        O       1
13        B        M       1
14        B        Q       1
15        B        L       1
16        B        Z       2
17        B        T       2
18        C        C       0
19        C        R       1
20        C        A       1
21        C        D       2
22        C        F       2
23        C        J       2
24        C        E       2
25        C        Y       2
26        C        B       2
27        D        D       0
28        D        F       1
29        D        H       1
30        D        I       1
31        D        E       1
32        D        A       2
33        D        C       2
34        D        S       2
35        D        U       3
```

Performance for 50k unique combinations of outer and inner keys:

```
np.random.seed(20)


from collections import defaultdict


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(100, size=50000),
                  'b': np.random.randint(500000000, size=50000),
                  'c': np.random.randint(20, size=50000)}).sort_values(['a','b']).drop_duplicates(['a','b'])

df[['a','b']] = 'a' + df[['a','b']].astype(str)

s = df.set_index(['a','b'])['c']
print (s)
a    b         
a0   a87201         6
     a1392645      12
     a1428929       9
     a2453757       8
     a2467544      14
                   ..
a99  a496111083    15
     a496689150     6
     a497489331     3
     a499160652    15
     a499359212     0
Name: c, Length: 50000, dtype: int32
```

---

```
d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}


In [210]: %%timeit
     ...: d2 = defaultdict(list)
     ...: for k, v in d.items():
     ...:     d2['person_1'] += [k] * len(v)
     ...:     d2['person_2'] += list(v.keys())
     ...:     d2['degree'] += list(v.values())
     ...: 
     ...: pd.DataFrame(d2)
     ...: 
     ...: 
21.2 ms ± 478 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [211]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.DataFrame([(k, k1, v1) for k, v in d.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()], columns=['person_1','person_2','degree'])
     ...: 
     ...: 
25.8 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [212]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.concat({x : pd.Series(y) for x , y in d.items()}).reset_index()
     ...: 
110 ms ± 3.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [213]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(d)
     ...: pd.melt(df).rename(columns = {'index': 'hcp_npi',  'variable':'connected_hcp_npi', 'value': 'degree_of_separation'}).dropna()
     ...: 
1.17 s ± 7.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Looks like I still win :) Interesting that the `melt` got so much slower but I guess that's what OP is seeing

Comment: @Nick - yop, agree.